# How many (Shannon) bits are there in one gram of 25° water?

Tags: entropy

Computing the thermodynamic entropy in a macro way (integrating the Clausius entropy from 0 K to 298.15 K) yields the value 3.9 J/g,K. This can also be found from tables on entropy for various substances.

My question now is the following: Is it ok to convert this value to Shannon information bits by dividing with kB (Boltzmann´s konstant) and rescaling from ln to lb (change of logarithm base) leading to 4*10^23 bits? 
(a) What would be a reasonable interpretation of this result? 
(b) If this is indeed a measure of the bits required to fully describe the micro-states of all water molecules, can it be computed directly from the statistical velocity (rotational etc) distribution of 25° water molecules?

Comment: Related [How is a "bit of information" defined in physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/298746/).  Short version : very loosely and not really usefully.

Answer (score 0):

They are probably asking you exactly what you've said for the Shannon entropy estimation part. The interpretation would be that, such amount of bits would be needed to sufficiently describe the state of the droplet, given that we treat the molecules as small balls and don't go into atom-level calculations.

If we use distributions, we can describe the states of the water molecules with some probability, thus not fully describe it. That is we know that molecule i  *probably*  has some velocity, position etc, but we are never certain. (This is NOT the same uncertainty as quantum mechanics as it is decoherent).

Comment: Thanks Luthelin. What puzzles me is that the information (Shannon entropy) of the current state can be computed by integrating through two phases (ice, water) including the phase transition. If instead, we focus on the velocity, position etc of the individual molecules only at 25°C to compute the Shannon entropy, how can it be understood that the two methods will give the same result?

Comment: As you increase temperature, there are more accessible states for the molecules, thus more information ( more bits to describe the system). Lets work with entropy from now on. The fact that there is a sudden jump in the entropy when the phases change is due to the fact that the ice loses its lattice. That is, Shannon entropy is defined as the number of bits needed to encode the state. If you have a lattice, you can just encode the lattice and the basis inside it, thus needing much less information than the position and velocity of every particle. This is why there is a jump in entropy.

Comment: Shannon entropy in information theory is defined as the bits needed regardless of the encoding (http://www.ueltschi.org/teaching/chapShannon.pdfhttp://www.ueltschi.org/teaching/chapShannon.pdf). That is, you can add the relative distances from each molecule to all others, thus needing a lot more bits, but that would not increase the entropy.